# how to convert string to other struct

Tags: go

current code

```
var rdi rules.RuleDirection
switch direction{
case "ingress":
    rdi = "ingress"
case "egress":
    rdi = "egress"
}
```

direction is string type
rdi is rules.RuleDirection type

how to convert direction to rdi ,not use current code, it is to complex

Comment: type RuleDirection string,  rdi=rules.RuleDirection("ingress").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `RuleDirection` appears to be derived from string:

```
rdi:=rules.RuleDirection(direction)
```

However, you might need to validate the value before conversion:

```
if direction!="ingress" && direction!="egress" { 
  // error
}
rdi:=rules.RuleDirection(direction)
```